# Make a set from CSV values in TSQL

Tags: t-sql

If I want to see which values from an Excel spreadsheet column don't match values in a table, I can easily create a table with Bulk Import. Is there a simpler way?
EG, I want to do a query like:

```
select into #temp from ('a', 'b', 'c') as 'Id'
select * from #temp where Id not in (select Id from MyTable)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [this UDF](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/06/sql-server-udf-function-to-convert-list-to-table/) to parse your list into a table.  Then you should be able to do the following:

```
SELECT * INTO #temp FROM dbo.udf_List2Table( 'a,b,c', ',') 
SELECT * FROM #temp WHERE item NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM MyTable)
```

Comment: You have a syntax error - the `INTO` statement must come before `FROM`

Comment: Thanks for this. I fixed some syntax errors for you. This is good, but doesn't seem to play nice with newlines in the string, so it's a bit of a pain to paste in from an Excel column.

Comment: Thanks Ed.  Fixed. @rossfabricant - I could see the new line causing problems.  Could you do some cleanup on your csv file before you past the comma seperated values into your query?  If you have Notepad++ this link might help you accomplish this: http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/newlineFindReplace-HOWTO.php

Answer (score 1):

Also, I've been using the additional column in Excel with bunch of CONCATENATE.TEXT commands to create the INSERT statements. This column alone, copied into the text file, is your script!

Comment: Thanks, good idea. However, it would be easier to be able to use a simpler formula or no formula at all when copying from Excel.